# How do I know if Tab Bar Controller index was changed programatically in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitabbarcontroller

So I am writing a little something in swift that uses a tab bar controller with four tabs, each are fully functioning on their own. However in the main tab I select the best value from an array and provide a link to it. The array is presented in the second tab.

I have a code like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // some other stuff

        if dataManager.ideas.count > 0 {
            lblAllTimeBest.text = "Our all time best with a rating of \(dataManager.ideas[dataManager.allTimeBest].averageRating)% is:"

            btnAllTimeBest.hidden = false
             btnAllTimeBest.setTitle(dataManager.ideas[dataManager.allTimeBest].title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        //and some more stuff
    }

    @IBAction func btnAllTimeBestTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```

I present the items of the array on the second tab based on array index. How do I pass the index (I store it in datamanager already) to the second tab OR how do I know on the second tab that it was presented using the button on the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these options (in order of "recommendedness"):

1. keep a reference to the second controller (or retrieve it *ad hoc* from the tab bar controller) and implement a message in the second controller that the first controller can call explicitly
2. send an `NSNotification` via `NSNotificationCenter` and listen to it in the second controller
3. (not recommended) use some kind of global variable that the second controller can check